# Dynamically extending JSX.IntrinsicElements with custom props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm developing a small library which wraps around react and adds some custom props to tthe existing react native ones.
So it should create components with the types of the predefined CustomProps and these correspondig to the provided `type` combined.

```tsx
type CustomProps = {
    foo?: boolean,
};

const Anchor = factory<CustomProps>({
    type: 'a',
});
```

In this example, auto completion should suggest `foo` alongside `href`, `rel` and so on.

This is what I've came up with:

```tsx
type TypeList = keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
type Factory = <Props, Type extends TypeList = TypeList>(
    {type}: Config<Props, Type>,
) => ForwardRefExoticComponent<JSX.IntrinsicElements[Type] & PropsWithChildren<Props>>;

type Config<Props, Type> = {
    type?: Type,
}
```

Technically speaking, it does work as intended, but `JSX.IntrinsicElements[Type]` in combination with `PropsWithChildren<Props>` creates absurdly big type definitions for some types like `button` or `div`.
rendering my IDE unresponsive sometimes.

Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: This sounds like an environment configuration question rather than a code question. Are you sure TS is the culprit? Your example seems adequately responsive to me, even in the [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N54Qow), which is running in an in-browser version of TS. What IDE are you using and which extensions have you enabled beyond the TypeScript language server?

Comment: I don't think, this has something to do with my IDE or extensions, as I'm working on projects hundredfold the size.
The thing is, if I'm going to build a component library with this example above. The generated definitions for the individual components would be enormous sometimes.
[Example for type="button"](https://pastebin.com/rZYwVbMY). Could this be a result of a misconfigured tsconfig?

Comment: @jsejcksn You need to add the type annotation to see the slow down. e.g. `factory<{}>({ type: "div" })`

@sovrin Seems like TypeScript is able to correctly infer the element type without a type annotation but when you add one your default is then used, `TypeList`, which presumably is why your editor becomes sluggish as it completes all 120 definitions then rather than one.